# rails routing list filter from html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So i want from this dropdown, to be able to select or basically filter, some drawings based on the workcategory they are at. Both models (Drawings and Workcategories) are connected with has_many drawings and belongs_to workcategories. The drawing holds the workcategory.id as foreign key, and i want to filter by it.This is what i've tried to build

```
<% @workcategories.each do |workcategory| %>
    <li><%= link_to workcategory.name, workcategory_list_path(workcategory.id) %></li>
<% end %>
```

While in the drawings controller i've added these :

```
before_filter :list    
def list
    @drawingsz = Drawing.order("drawings.id ASC").where(:workcategory_id => @workcategory.try(:id))
end
```

The problem is, whenever i press one of the workcategories inserted, it shows me all the drawings. I've tried from this basic variation to others, including some routings. Oh and talk about routings, i have this :

```
  resources :workcategories do
    get :list, :controller => :drawings
    resources :drawings
  end
  resources :drawings
```

any ideas ? i've browsed the forums a lot last night, and also the routes pages on the official docus, but i just can't get myself around it. I would like the pages to be basically like : /*workcategory.name*/drawings. Thank you !!

**update - added controller**

```
class DrawingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_drawing, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_filter :list
    def index
        @drawings = Drawing.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def new
        @drawing = Drawing.new
    end

    def create
        @drawing = Drawing.new(drawing_params)
        if @drawing.save
            flash[:notice] = "Drawing created"
            redirect_to(:action=>'index', :drawing_id => @drawing.id)
        else
            @drawings = Drawings.order()
            render('new')
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @drawing.update_attributes(drawing_params)
            flash[:notice] = "Drawing updated."
            redirect_to(:action=>"index")
        else
            render("edit")
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @drawing.destroy
        redirect_to drawings_path
    end
    def list
        @drawingsz = Drawing.order("drawings.id ASC").where(:workcategory_id => @workcategory.try(:name))
    end

    private
    def find_drawing
        @drawing=Drawing.find(params[:id])
    end

    def drawing_params
        params.require(:drawing).permit(:name, :description, :image)
    end

end
```

**View update**
This is the new view update - which doesn't work, due to another error.

```
<% @workcategories.each do |workcategory| %>
        <li><%= link_to workcategory.name, {:controller => 'drawings', :action => 'list', :workcategory_id => workcategory.id } %></li>
<% end %>
```

I've updated the list to this :

```
def list
    @workcategory_id = params[:workcategory_id] 
    if @workcategory_id
        @drawingz = Drawing.find(params[:workcategory_id]).workcategory_id
    end
end
```

Now i get the error

> Couldn't find Drawing with 'id'=2015

Which is odd, because 2015 is in the names, not in the ids. I feel i'm much closer now but something is still missing ....

Comment: now that i think about it, it might make more sense to have the pages routed like drawings/workcategory.name ... i tried this too, but without success

Comment: please show your the view and full controller

Comment: hello, i've added the controller, but i don't know what you mean my views, there are more files there. any one in particular ?

Comment: hi, I mean the view (or layout) where you render the dropdown

Comment: added .. and added some updates as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is cleaned up version of what you are trying to do:

1. `routes.rb`

   ```
   resources :workcategories do
     get :drawings, to: 'drawings#workcategory_drawings'
   end
   resources :drawings
   ```

This gives you:

`/workcategories/:workcategory_id/drawings => drawings#workcategory_drawings`

2. `drawings_controller.rb`

   ```
   ..
   def workcategory_drawings
     @drawings = Drawing.where(workcategory_id: params[:workcategory_id]).all
   end
   ..
   ```

(no need for `before_action :list`)

3. The dropdown (assuming that you have initialized `@workcategories` somewhere)

   ```
   <% @workcategories.each do |workcategory| %>
     <li>
       <%= link_to workcategory.name, workcategory_drawings_path(workcategory) %>
     </li>
   <% end %>
   ```

Comment: hey thank you ! it's improved now ... the coding is cleaner and i've learned something new about paths. but the code still doesn't work as i intended. On the dropmenu if i choose the workcategory with id 1 it shows me the items, but for anything else it doesn't show me anything. Any idea ?

Comment: you are welcome. what exactly do you mean by `anything else`?

Comment: i mean if i press the button(dropdown) on some other workcategory that isn't listed as id=1, it does not work :) if i go to id 2,3 etc, the page shows as blank

Comment: Are you sure that there are drawings associated with other categories? You could set a breakpoint and check this in console

Comment: ok so .. because i don't know how to use the breakpoint, i tried hardcoding the 'params[:workcategory_id]' to some other id, to see if that's the problem. and it still didn't work. when i hardcoded it, nothing was on the screen. I also checked the console log, and it shows me the sql query is alright So the problem is from somewhere else ... and not your solution/code. But i'm clueless about it .. it's probably something in the view template. Any clues ? i'm starting to regret not going for the easy approach being my first website and went for this tricky stuff :/

Comment: Ok I see. I'd suggest you to get friendly with debugging tools. e.g. check this [cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails?autoplay=true)

Comment: After you install it you can set a breakpoint even in the view (`<% binding.pry %>`) and check available variables from console

Comment: oy thanks ! problem solved ! the problem was somewhere else in the _form of the drawing !